# Regex matching plus or minus

Tags: ruby, regex

Could someone please look at the following function and explain the regex for me as I don't understand it and I don't like using something I don't understand as then I won't be able to replicate it for use in the future and nor do I learn from it.

Also can someone explain the double !! in front, I know single means not so does double mean not "not"?

The function is a patch to `String` to check if it's capable of being converted to an integer or not.

```
class String 
    def is_i?
        !!(self =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z/) 
    end
end
```

The main thing that's giving me trouble is `[-+]` as it makes little sense to me, if you could explain in the context given it would be very helpful.

EDIT:
Since people missed the second part of the question I'll be a little more explicit.

What does `!!` Mean in front of the check, I know a single `!` means NOT but I can't find what `!!` means.

Comment: The question "how does this code work" is only marginally better than "why isn't this code working". Although the question is about programming, it is very unlikely that it would help other users.

Comment: If you want to know what `!!` means, ask a question "What does !! mean in Ruby`.

Comment: I just wanted the code explained because I wasn't sure what it meant, I tried to work through it but the first character class `[-+]` and the double `!!` through me off, I don't like using code if I don't understand it. That's all there is to it, as far as I'm concerned it's completely different from asking why it doesn't work, as that is asking for a solution to a problem; I'm asking for an explanation of how it works so I can better understand and thus learn.

Comment: Also I did, I googled that and got no help, all I got was "X number of reasons as to why you should program in ruby" that or some unrelated results. That's why I'm asking as an extra part to my main question.

Comment: It's a fair point; searching for terms with punctuation characters in them can be frustrating.  I find [this site](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+!!) very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `[-+]` Character Class

`[-+]` is a character class. It means "match **one** character specified by  the class", i.e. `-` or `+`.

**Hyphens in Character Classes**

I can see how this particular class can be confusing because the hyphen often plays a special role in a character class: it links two characters to form a character range. For instance, `[a-z]` means "match one character between `a` and `z`, and `[a-z0-9]` means "match one character between `a` and `z` or between `0` and `9`.

However, in this case, the hypen in `[-+]` is positioned in a place where it cannot be used to specify a range, and the `-` is just a literal hyphen.

**Decoding the entire expression**

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `\A`
- Match a single character from the list “-+” `[-+]?`

  - Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
- Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]+`

  - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
- Assert position at the very end of the string `\z`

Answer (score 1):

A [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) defines a set of characters, any one of which can occur in a string for a match to succeed.

For example, the regular expression `[-+]?[0-9]+` will match `123`, `-123`, or `+123` because it defines a character class (accepting either `-`, `+`, or neither one) as its first character.

In context:

- `\A` asserts position at the start of the string.
- `[-+]` any character of: `-` or `+` (`?` *optional*, meaning between **zero** and **one** time)
- `[0-9]` any character of: `0` to `9` (`+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) meaning **1** or more times)
- `\z` asserts position at the very end of the string.

### What does `!!` mean?

`!!` placed together converts the value to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

> explain the regex for me as I don't understand it

Pattern explanation: `\A[-+]?[0-9]+\z`

```
\A       Start of string
[-+]?    plus or minus sign [zero or one time (optional)]
[0-9]+   0 to 9 any digit [one or more times]
\z       End of string
```

The above regex pattern is able to match any positive and negative integer number that has `+` or `-` sign optional.

Read more about [Character Classes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) and test your regex pattern online at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)